# placement in a stack according to position -help figure out function

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to figure out a case where I have a vertical green line that represents a stack of layers and a red "plank" that represents currently focused layer out of the stack.

I need to make sure when top most layer is selected - the plank is at the top of the green line. When first (deepest) layer is selected the plank is at the bottom of the green line.

Using the function below I can achieve the #1 condition, but whenever I select deepest layer - I can't get red plank placed at the bottom.

I know this should be school level math exercise but I cant figure it out;/

UPDATE: so in the snippet if I will do current Layer 1 and total N/whatever. I cant "land" the plank onto the bottom of the line

UPDATE2: OK I added some more logic to the function and now the result is what I need. PRoblem is I am not sure I achieved this through proper logic. At least I don't really understand what I did and why it now works.

```js
// trying to figure out better function to indicate which is current layer:
// height of the green line is 280.

var currentItemLayer = 3;
var totalLayers = 4;
var plank = document.getElementById("plank");

setPlankPositionAccordingToLayer = function(currentItemLayer, totalLayers) {
    var blockCount = Math.max(1, totalLayers - 1);
    var blockSize = 280*(1/blockCount);
    var layer;
    if (blockCount === 1) {
      layer = 100;
    } else {
      layer = 380-(currentItemLayer*blockSize);
    }
    plank.setAttribute("y", layer);
    console.log(layer);
};

setPlankPositionAccordingToLayer(currentItemLayer, totalLayers)
```

```html
<body>
<svg id="mainSVG"
viewBox="0 0 480 480"
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin"
width="100%"
height="100%"
background-color="white"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
<line x1="240" y1="100" x2="240" y2="380" style="stroke: green"/>
<rect id="plank" x="230" y="240" width="20" height="2"/>
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Is including 0 (zero) as `currentItemLayer` an option? if yes, that would solve it as far as i can tell. Just remember to subtract 1 from `totalLayers` in that case.

Comment: Your layer's vertical size is much greater than the vertical size of the plank. So that is why the plank does not reach the very top when it is at the top layer. It is positioned at the bottom of the top layer. Why not give the plank the same height as the layer's height? NB: for reaching the bottom layer, the layer number should be 0, not 1.

Comment: I will try with 0. in the snippet that works for sure;) if that suits - I will mark as answer! (can't believe it is as easy as that,...)

Comment: OK so the approach to have 0 layer is good but only solves half of the problem. Assume we say current layer = 0 and total layers count is 4 - everything renders perfect. Now we want to say its layer 3 (which would be the last layer if total is 4) - and we again can't hit to top;///

Comment: I made changes to the script, now it works as intended (I think) but I am not sure this is logically correct how I do that.